# how put defaults values in url route to make url freandly in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I need to put defaults values in url with laravel routing when parameters are empty or null. i think something like this (obviously not found) but is for you get my idea.

```
Route::get('/filtro/{event_type?}-en-{location?}/{caption?}', [
    'uses' => 'ProviderController@filter',
    'as' => 'site_filter_path'
])->defaults([
    'event_type' => 'todos',
    'location' => 'argentina'
]);
```

so when parameters are empty the url could be mysite.com/filtro/todos-en-argentina/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass null value to your route. But it should not be empty.

Comment: That is fine but it only serves me for the controller, I need to create a url with this data by default, I explain?

Answer (score 0):

Make two routes.

In routes file:

```
Route::get('/filtro', 'ProviderController@filter')->named('filtro');
Route::get('/filtro/{event_type?}-en-{location?}/{caption?}', 'ProviderController@filter')->named('site_filter_path');
```

In ProviderController:

```
public function filter($event_type = null, $location = null, $caption = null){
   if(!$event_type) $event_type = 'todos';
   If(!$location) $location = 'argentina';   
   //your code
}
```